# Saving a QImage from a memory buffer

Tags: c++, qt

Here is basically what I'm doing :

I have a video stream (YUV format). Each frame is extracted into a buffer (`frameBytes`). Later, this buffer is used to do the YUV->RGB conversion, then transfered in an `IplImage`. The `IplImage` is then transfered into a `cv::Mat` and displayed in an OpenGL context. Everything works fine.

What I would like to do is bypass the `IplImage` and `cv::Mat` section to directly work with the `frameBytes` buffer in OpenGL and do the conversion in the shaders.

This explaination is just for the context, since the problem I'm having is simpler.

To see if I can work with the buffer earlier, I try to copy it with memcpy and then save it in a `QImage` then in a file.

**Here is my code for this part :**

```
unsigned char *mycopy = new unsigned char[1920*1080*3];
memcpy(mycopy, frameBytes, sizeof(1920*1080*3));
QImage *img = new QImage(mycopy, 1920, 1080, QImage::Format_RGB888);
img->save("image.jpg",0,-1);
```

frameBytes contains the YUV data from the video stream. I know it's YUV and I'm trying to create a QImage with RGB888 format but since QImage doesn't support the format, I didn't make the conversion there, I thought it would still save an image but with the wrong colors so I don't care for the moment (Maybe this assumption is wrong ?).

**Problem is, the image saved is black.**

Just for more information, here is an example where I use `frameBytes` for the YUV->RGB conversion.

```
void DeckLinkCaptureDelegate::convertFrameToOpenCV(void* frameBytes, IplImage * m_RGB){
    if(!m_RGB)  m_RGB = cvCreateImage(cvSize(1920, 1080), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);


    unsigned char* pData = (unsigned char *) frameBytes;


    for(int i = 0, j=0; i < 1920 * 1080 * 3; i+=6, j+=4)
    {

        unsigned char u = pData[j];
        unsigned char y = pData[j+1];
        unsigned char v = pData[j+2];

        //fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", v);
        m_RGB->imageData[i+2] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        m_RGB->imageData[i+1] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        m_RGB->imageData[i] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;                            // b

        y = pData[j+3];
        m_RGB->imageData[i+5] = 1.0*y + 8 + 1.402*(v-128);               // r
        m_RGB->imageData[i+4] = 1.0*y - 0.34413*(u-128) - 0.71414*(v-128);   // g
        m_RGB->imageData[i+3] = 1.0*y + 1.772*(u-128) + 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: why sizeof(1920*1080*3) and not simply 1920*1080*3? sizeof(1920*1080*3) is the same of sizeof(int)

Comment: It solved the problem. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fixing the bug

You didn't copy all the data to your new buffer:

```
unsigned char *mycopy = new unsigned char[1920*1080*3];
memcpy(mycopy, frameBytes, sizeof(1920*1080*3));
```

That `sizeof` in there means that you're only copying an `int`-sized block, rather than 6MB.  It looks like an accidental holdover from using a static array?  Replace it with

```
const size_t bufsize = 1920*1080*3;
auto *mycopy = new unsigned char[bufsize];
memcpy(mycopy, frameBytes, bufsize);
```

---

### A simpler approach

Alternatively, instead of doing the memory allocation yourself (and being responsible for `delete[]`ing it after the `QImage` is destructed), you could copy the image instead:

```
const unsigned char *bytes = frameBytes;
QImage img = QImage(bytes, 1920, 1080, QImage::Format_RGB888).copy();
```

The way this works is that we create a temporary `QImage` using `frameBytes` as its source (we pass it as pointer to `const` to insist it's read-only).  We then `copy()` the whole of it to a new `QImage`, throwing away the temporary.  The `copy()` does something similar to your code above, but we're now saved from having to do the calculations, eliminating some of the consequent potential for error.

Note also that I prefer to pass `QImage` by value.  Although this might seem inefficient, most (copyable) Qt types are designed as reference-counted copy-on-write structures, and can be safely used this way, eliminating another class of errors (memory management).  This is true of Qt's collection types, too, and very useful.